# MapServer square symbol composed of 4 internal squares

Tags: vector, symbology, mapserver

I need to create simple square symbol composed of 4 internal squares.

```
SYMBOL
    NAME 'SQUARE_TL'
    TYPE vector
    FILLED true
    POINTS
        0 0
        0 0.5
        0.5 0.5
        0.5 0
        0 0
    END
END

SYMBOL
    NAME 'SQUARE_BL'
    TYPE vector
    FILLED true
    POINTS
        0 0.5
        0 1
        0.5 1
        0.5 0.5
        0 0.5
    END
END

SYMBOL
    NAME 'SQUARE_BR'
    TYPE vector
    FILLED true
    POINTS
        0.5 0.5
        0.5 1
        1 1
        1 0.5
        0.5 0.5
    END
END

SYMBOL
    NAME 'SQUARE_TR'
    TYPE vector
    FILLED true
    POINTS
        0.5 0
        0.5 0.5
        1 0.5
        1 0
        0.5 0
     END
END


LAYER
    NAME "test1"
    TYPE POINT
    STATUS off
    CLASS
        NAME "test1"
        EXPRESSION ([test_value]>0)  # if > 0 shows 4 sections square
        STYLE
            SYMBOL "SQUARE_TL"
            COLOR 0 255 0
            SIZE 14
        END
        STYLE
            SYMBOL "SQUARE_BL"
            COLOR 255 0 0
            SIZE 14
        END
        STYLE
            SYMBOL "SQUARE_BR"
            COLOR 100 100 100
            SIZE 14
        END
        STYLE
            SYMBOL "SQUARE_TR"
            COLOR 0 0 255
            SIZE 14
        END
    END
    **
*
```

TopLeft (TL) is green

BottomLeft (BL) is red

BottomRight (BR) is grey

TopRight (TR) is blue

But when I implement a CLASS LAYER STYLE with all of them I get this strange shifted/wrong square:

[image]

If I implement only top-left and bottom-right

```
    CLASS
        NAME "test1"
        EXPRESSION ([test1]>0)  # if > 0 shows 4 sections square
        STYLE
            SYMBOL "SQUARE_TL"
            COLOR 0 255 0
            SIZE 14
        END
        STYLE
            SYMBOL "SQUARE_BR"
            COLOR 100 100 100
            SIZE 14
        END
    END
```

I get

[image]

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean to have 1-4 adjacent color boxes at bottom-left, top-left, bottom-right, and top-right positions then I would do it by having one square symbol with points

```
 POINTS
    0 0
    0 1
    1 1
    1 0
    0 0
 END
```

Then I would make four copies of the symbol with different ANCHORPOINTs as documented in http://www.mapserver.org/mapfile/symbol.html.

The final mapfile with the four styles and one inline feature as data:

```
SYMBOL
    NAME 'SQUARE_TL'
    TYPE vector
    FILLED true
 POINTS
    0 0
    0 1
    1 1
    1 0
    0 0
 END
 ANCHORPOINT 1 1
 END

SYMBOL
    NAME 'SQUARE_BL'
    TYPE vector
    FILLED true
 POINTS
    0 0
    0 1
    1 1
    1 0
    0 0
 END
 ANCHORPOINT 1 0
 END

SYMBOL
    NAME 'SQUARE_TR'
    TYPE vector
    FILLED true
 POINTS
    0 0
    0 1
    1 1
    1 0
    0 0
 END
 ANCHORPOINT 0 1 
 END

SYMBOL
    NAME 'SQUARE_BR'
    TYPE vector
    FILLED true
 POINTS
    0 0
    0 1
    1 1
    1 0
    0 0
 END
 ANCHORPOINT 0 0
 END 


LAYER
    NAME "test1"
    TYPE POINT
    STATUS on
    FEATURE
        POINTS
        10 10
        END
   END
    CLASS
        NAME "test1"
        STYLE
            SYMBOL "SQUARE_TL"
            COLOR 0 255 0  #green
            SIZE 14
        END
           STYLE
            SYMBOL "SQUARE_BL" 
            COLOR 255 0 0 #red
            SIZE 14
        END   
          STYLE
        SYMBOL "SQUARE_TR"
        COLOR 0 0 255 #blue
        SIZE 14
        END    
          STYLE
        SYMBOL "SQUARE_BR"
        COLOR 100 100 100 #grey
        SIZE 14
        END    
    END
    END
```

The result looks like this (data point highlighted only for showing how the four boxes are places, yellow point does not come from MapServer).

[image]